# Unable to Catch exception in java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

#### Scenario:

I am using a [project](https://github.com/reindahl/jmtp/tree/master/java) to manage MPT with Java.

I've got a piece of code like:

```
try {
    originalfilename = m_allFiles[i].getOriginalFileName();
} catch (Exception e)  {
    System.out.println("Exception Caught");
}
```

As I access the objects from different threads, sometimes this instruction throws an exception like [be.derycke.pieter.com.COMException](https://github.com/reindahl/jmtp/blob/master/java/src/be/derycke/pieter/com/COMException.java)

#### Problem:

The message *"Exception Caught"* is never printed and console prints this stack trace:

```
be.derycke.pieter.com.COMException: Failed to retrieve the properties (0x800700aa)
    at jmtp.PortableDevicePropertiesImplWin32.getValues(Native Method)
    at jmtp.PortableDeviceObjectImplWin32.retrieveStringValue(Unknown Source)
    at jmtp.PortableDeviceObjectImplWin32.getOriginalFileName(Unknown Source)
    at com.servifot.kiosco.MobileCableSearcher$MobileFolderSearcher.run(MobileCableSearcher.java:284)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The "MobileCableSearcher.java:284" line is what I have inside the try. So **why the catch is not catching the exception?**

#### More info:

The object which I call getOriginalFilename() is a [PortableDeviceObject](https://github.com/reindahl/jmtp/blob/master/java/src/jmtp/PortableDeviceObject.java)

I've tried to Catch a *Throwable* but the problem is exactly the same.

I've tried to specify the exception with be.derycke.pieter.com.COMException but I get this error:
[image]

Comment: Can you identify code that print this message? Is it possible that message is printed inside the lib and exception is newer thrown from `getOriginalFileName`?

Comment: `be.derycke.pieter.com.COMException` is a checked exception and thus can't be thrown by `PortableDeviceObject.getOriginalFilename()` because it doesn't declare that exception to be thrown and implementing methods are not allowed to add a throws declaration.

Comment: Unrelated: please learn about java naming conventions. Using "m_" hungarian notation style naming schemes are discouraged for java source code.

Comment: Check your log. It should contain line "Errror in retrieveStringValue. HRESULT" right before exception.

Comment: Further to @Thomas comment, if you put a `println` after the quoted code, is that executed?

Comment: That exception seems to be thrown within a thread. It is probably caught by the JVM's default exception handler, not by the catch clause you provide.

Comment: @Thomas thank you for the answer. That's the problem as talex sais in his answer.

Comment: @GhostCat Ok, I'll have a look. That's what my boss told me to do, and that's what we do, but I'll try to improve the naming. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, Team rules override other practices. But it basically means that you make it harder to onboard people familiar with these common practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception is caught and reported in `PortableDeviceObjectImplWin32.retrieveStringValue`.

You will get `null` as result of `getOriginalFileName` in this case.